# Using promises to fill an array with data from an external API

Tags: javascript, express

What I'm trying to do is to fill an array with a series of objects of stock data that I am getting from a third party external API. Ideally, the array would be filled up in order of the stock tickers that I have in my array called tickers. However, when I hit the endpoint, all I see is an empty array. Why doesn't this code work and what would a solution using async/await look like?

```
const tickers = ['HAL','MSFT', 'AAPL']
let bodies = []
app.get('/api/allQuotes', async function(req, res, next) { 
    for (let i = 0 ; i < tickers.length; i++) {
        console.log(tickers[i])
        getRawApiResponse("https://finnhub.io/api/v1/quote?symbol=" + tickers[i] + "&token=################") 
        .then(body => {
            console.log("Index >" + body);
            bodies.push(body);
    
        });

    }
    
    res.json(bodies);
});

console.log(bodies);
function getRawApiResponse(uri) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get({ uri }, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
        resolve(body);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following code:

```js
let url = (x: string) => `https://finnhub.io/api/v1/quote?symbol=${x}&token=################`;

app.get('/api/allQuotes', async function (req, res, next) {
  const bodies = await Promise.all([...Array(tickers.length).keys()].map(x => getRawApiResponse(url(tickers[x]))));
  res.json(bodies);
});
```